# a disproportionate amount of dead objects were detected

Tags: c#, .net, memory, garbage-collection

I made a simple example to showcase the problem. I have a blazor project with a page that call a function:

```
<button @onclick='(() => TestMemory())'>Insert Memory</button>

<h3>Times function is run: @counter</h3>

@code {
    int counter = 0;

    public void TestMemory()
    {
        _agp.TestClas();
        counter++;
    }    
}
```

Function that is called:

```
public void TestClas()
{
    List<TestClass> testList = new List<TestClass>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        testList.Add(new TestClass() { ArtId = i });
    }
}
```

testList doesn't exists outside of the scope of the function.
Every time I perform the function heapsize doesn't change much:

[image]

Yet process Memory keeps growing and i don't see it shrinking. In the memory analyzer of visual studio is get the following warning:

enter image description here

Why do this dead objects stay in memory until the program is closed and how can I prevent it?

tried: Clear the list, list = null, list.TrimExcess().

Comment: Garbage collection doesn't run until there's memory pressure - you can try sticking a `GC.Collect(0);` in `TestMemory()` after the call to `TestClas()` to force it to run.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same message, but even forcing the Garbage Collector to run was pointless.

The fact was that the objects I was dealing with were allocated on the Large Object Heap, a memory area handled in a different way by the GC - I don't know if the same applies to your case.

I've solved the issue changing the GC behaviour:

```
System.Runtime.GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = System.Runtime.GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
```

and then forcing GC to run:

```
System.GC.Collect();
```

but you can also simply set the value of **LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode** and leave the rest to the next occurring garbage collection.

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode):

> The default value of the **LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode** property is
> **GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.Default**, which indicates that the LOH is not compacted during garbage collections. If you assign the
> property a value of
> **GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce**, the LOH is compacted during the next full blocking garbage collection, and the property
> value is reset to **GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.Default**.